# Injecting string into src attribute

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to add to a src of multiple images using jQuery as follows:

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

to

```
<img src="image-thumb.jpg">
```

For some reason I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a class to the img tags you want the script to affect (e.g. `<img src="image.jpg" class="foo">`).

Then, use jQuery's [`.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the `src` attribute of all the img tags you want:

```
$('.foo').attr('src', 'image-thumb.jpg');
```

If your images are named differently and you just want to add `-thumb` to each one all at once, use a callback function:

```
$('.foo').attr('src', function(index, attr) {
    return attr.replace(/\.[^.]*$/, '-thumb$&');
});
```

In this second code example, I am using a regular expression to find and replace the ending of the image URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#something img').each(function() {

   var src = $(this).attr('src').replace(/(\.\w*)$/, '-thumb$1');

   $(this).attr({ src: src });

});
```

[See it](http://jsbin.com/ukije5/edit).

Idealmachine's last example in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170504/injecting-string-into-src-attribute/4170526#4170526) is a cleaner way of doing what I suggested above (that is if that is the only manipulation you are doing on the `img` element).

So we both remember...

- `attr()` can take a function as its second argument - to make these sort of things easier.
- `$&` is the backreference to the entire matched string - no need to wrap with parenthesis like I did.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ID of the image you can use `$("#img").attr("src","second.jpg");`

You can also access the src attribute using `$("#img").attr("src");`.  The rest is just doing the string replacement.

Comment: The ID's will be changing. I am attempting to copy a list of images and then append them as thumbnails to another list.

Comment: How is the list of images organized?